# Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on Gigabyte GA-C847N board - no Ethernet detected

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

I am running a fresh install of 16.04 Desktop 64-bit on a Gigabyte GA-C847N motherboard and the Realtek dual-ethernet card is not detected at all.

Running `sudo lshw -c network` shows the wireless interface (an Edmax USB wifi card installed to get online) but nothing else.

I have tried manually installing the drivers with `sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms` with no success.

Is there anything else I can try to see if the Ethernet card is actually working or if it might be fried?

Many thanks

Edit: output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` is blank

alex@alex-itx:~$ sudo lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2

[sudo] password for alex:

alex@alex-itx:~$

Yes, both ports are enabled in BIOS - using Legacy and UEFI mode.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A2` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: And is it enabled in UEFI? You probably checked it already but just in case... It wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - post edited to reflect the answers.

Comment: I am beginning to think the 2 x Eth ports on the board are fried. Not uncommon here in Brazil. I am getting a cheap PCI 10/100/1000 to test next weekend.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem installing Ubuntu 64 bit on Gigabyte motherboards. Usb 2.0 and ethernet won't work.
Try to install from USB 3.0 port. It worked for me. If not, go to BIOS and change UIMMO configuraton.

This problem is fixed on this thread. It works for (all?) Gigabyte motherboards:

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=4